# Why would Nginx serve files correctly from the default directory but not new directory?

Tags: nginx, centos

**Installation**

**OS**: CentOS 7.4

**Server**: Nginx 1.12.2

---

**Question:** My nginx installation serves files without problem from the default directory, `/usr/share/nginx/html`.  Unfortunately I get a 403 error when I use a new folder that I created, `/www/html`.  What should I look for?

My permissions are identical for both folders although the owner is different.

**Original default folder**

`drwxr-xr-x.   13 root  root         155 Jan  8 09:25 usr`

**New default folder**

`drwxr-xr-x.   3 first first         18 Jan 15 10:45 www`

I am using the stripped down `nginx.conf` file below and it works correctly.

```
events {}

http {

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  mydomain.com;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

}
```

However when I change `nginx.conf` to use this directory `/www/html` I get a 403 error.

Thanks for any help in advance!  I'm a noob and not even sure where to look beyond file permissions.

---

**UPDATE**

SELinux is enabled in enforcing mode.

```
[first@centos-2gb-sfo1-01 log]$ sestatus
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
Loaded policy name:             targeted
Current mode:                   enforcing
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy MLS status:              enabled
Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
Max kernel policy version:      28
```

---

**2nd UPDATE**
I updated `nginx.conf` to include an error log.

```
events {}

http {

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  projournal.com;
        root         /www/html;
        error_log    /var/log/nginx.error.log;
    }

}
```

`nginx.error.log` was created in the correct directory but after several 403 errors it was still blank.

Comment: It's probably permissions - the user running as Nginx probably doesn't have permission to read from the new folder. Please edit your question to include the Nginx configuration that works and the one that doesn't, and an Nginx error log that shows the error.

Comment: Do you have SElinux set to enforcing ?

Comment: Does the default directory contain an index file while your new folder does not?

Comment: Add `error_log /var/log/nginx.error.log;` to your config and check the log file for more information.

Comment: @lain SELinux is enabled and set to enforcing.  I included that in my update above.  What does that mean?

Comment: SELinux is additional security for linux. Maybe you can share the result of command 'ls -Z /path/to/your/folder'? To check if it's because selinux disable it first by using 'setenforce 0' then access the web again. And please add error_log in the configuration as @mjb2km suggest.

Comment: @mjb2kmn @Ilham Sulaksono  I added the error log and included another update above.  I reloaded `nginx.conf` with `sudo systemctl reload nginx.service`. After triggering several 403 errors I checked `nginx.error.log` and it was blank.

Comment: Use `/srv/www` instead, to avoid SELinux issues like this.

Comment: @Michael Hampton That was a good idea!  However I changed it to `root         /srv/www/html;` uploaded my index.htm file, set the ownership and permissions, reloaded nginx and still got a 403.  Dang!

Comment: Did you check the SELinux contexts on the directories and files, and check the audit log?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With SELinux enforcing, httpd will be denied access to /www/html as files will not have the correct context.

```
matchpathcon /www/html
/www/html       system_u:object_r:default_t:s0
```

If you really want to use /www/html then you can add an appropriate path context to the database

```
semanage fcontext -a -t "httpd_sys_content_t" /www/html(/.*)?
```

There are though a number of default locations that can be used that already have the correct context already defined e.g. /var/www/html, /srv/www etc.

As you created /srv/www, you need to initially set it's SELinux context after which (normally) any new files and directories will have the correct context.

```
restorecon -v /srv/www
```

Will 'fix' /srv/www. You have though already populated /srv/www so you will need to set the file contexts for the whole tree

```
restorecon -Rv /srv/www
```